# Parameter of union type of enums?

Tags: typescript, react-native, enums, union

What I have are two enums

```
enum Fruit { Apples, Oranges };
enum Vegetable { Garlic, Cucumber };
```

and a type

```
type Food = Fruit | Vegetable;
```

Now I want to make another type that is a function and takes a food as a parameter

```
type OnViewFood = (food: Food) => void;
```

But when I do

```
viewFruit: OnViewFood = (fruit: Fruit) => `This is ${fruit}`;
```

I get an error that Food is not assignable to Fruit.
How do I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the compiler doesn't want you to do this is because it is essentially not safe. Consider if this example were valid:

```
// we assign a function that can only handle Fruit.
let viewFruit: OnViewFood = (fruit: Fruit) => `This is ${fruit}`; 

// the declared signature allows us to use a Vegetable, 
// possibly causing an error
viewFruit(Vegetable.Cucumber);
```

You can declare `OnViewFood` to be a union of functions, but then calling becomes an issue since you can't call a union of functions and you can't easily type-guard :

```
type OnViewFood = ((food: Fruit) => void) | ((food: Vegetable) => void);
let viewFruit: OnViewFood = (fruit: Fruit) => `This is ${fruit}`;

// ok now can be either function signature 
viewFruit(Vegetable.Cucumber); // now an error
```

In either case we can use a type assertion to get around the type error, and you can go for either option, depending on which side you trust more, the function creator side or the caller side:

```
// Type assertion on call 
type OnViewFood = ((food: Fruit) => void) | ((food: Vegetable) => void);
let viewFruit: OnViewFood = (fruit: Fruit) => `This is ${fruit}`;

(viewFruit as any as ((food: Vegetable) => void))(Vegetable.Cucumber);

// Type assertion on declaration 
type OnViewFood = (food: Food) => void
let viewFruit: OnViewFood = ((fruit: Fruit) => `This is ${fruit}`) as (food: Food) => void;
viewFruit(Vegetable.Cucumber);
```

Comment: With the original code I was getting an error `OnViewFood only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` Not sure why.What is the recommended way of calling a function with type alias?